# iOS5: how to determine if the Notification Center for the app is turned ON/OFF

Tags: ios, iphone, apple-push-notifications

I want to respect my users' intent and not call `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(...)]` if they've turned off remote notifications for my app.

When calling `UIRemoteNotificationType enabledTypes = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] enabledRemoteNotificationTypes]`, I get the info on what types of notifications are enabled for my app. However, the Notification Center for this app can be turned OFF and I still get the previously enabled notification type from this method until I select "None".

Thus my app thinks notifications are enabled even when they aren't.

Is there a way to programatically find out the Notification Center status for my app? (ON/OFF).

Comment: If notifications are off and you do register, do you get `-application:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:` or `-application:didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:`? I wouldn't be surprised if the latter is invoked.

Comment: For me only the first method is executed when the notification center setting is either on or off. But the question is how to tell what it is set to from that method.

Comment: Calling `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(...)]` will do nothing that user can see if notifications for your app are turned off in Settings, why you don't want to call it each time?

Comment: It's not that I don't want to call it each time - I do - but I'd rather call my server and unregister the device from notifications as soon as I find out the user turned the notification center off.

Comment: Looks like Apple introduced the Notification Center ON/OFF switch but forgot to give us an API to query it... very frustrating.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Don't confuse "in the notification center" with "push notifications enabled." I can remove an app from the notification center but still have it receiving push notifications in the form of badge numbers, so your old method should work fine.

Comment: That is helpful but is there a way to check if the application is in the notification center pragmatically ?

Comment: I don't believe there is any way to tell what the user's notification settings are for your app beyond the app delegate methods to register and fail to register for remote notifications.